# Function inside of Object generating different print output than stand-alone function in Python 3.5

Tags: python

I have the following stand-alone function for printing arguments:

```
def multiArgsPrinter2(*args):
    testString = '';
    for count, thing in enumerate(args):
        testString += str(thing) + ","

    return testString
```

Which when run like this:

```
retval = multiArgsPrinter2(20, 30, 40)
print(retval)
```

prints 20,30,40, - as expected. I then make a class with this functionality inside:

```
class TestHelper2:
    """The TestHelper Class"""

    def multiArgsPrinter3(*args):
        testString = '';
        for count, thing in enumerate(args):
            testString += str(thing) + ","

        print(testString)
        return testString
```

No matter where I print this result, either as a returned value or inside the class the output I get looks like this:

```
<TestHelper2.TestHelper2 object at 0x00F6ABB0>,20,30,40,
```

which puzzles me. Any clues to what I'm not grasping?

Bonus points if you can tell me why calling yet another function inside an object has a habit of causing parentheses () to be attached around the return value?

Comment: As for your bonus points question, that should be a separate question with an example of what you mean. As it is, I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I resolved the 'bonus points' matter. I mistakenly passed the 'args' variable to another member function without the asterisk (*) attached basically leaving it as a list and thus eventually producing parentheses upon output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions defined in a class are by default **instance methods**. This means that they are implicitly passed an instance of the class and the function signature should reflect that. For example:

```
class Example:
    def print_stuff(self, *args):
        print 'My *self* is {}'.format(self)
        print 'My *args* is {}'.format(args)

Example().print_stuff(1, 2, 3)
# My *self* is <__main__.Example instance at 0x012D4210>
# My *args* is (1, 2, 3)
```

Python provides two decorators in order to change the signature of a function defined inside a class, `staticmethod` and `classmethod`. They are most often used with the decorator syntax (beyond the scope of this response) and are functions that accept a function as an argument and return a new, altered function.

`staticmethod` removes the implicit `self` argument from a function inside a class.

```
class Example:
    @staticmethod
    def print_stuff(*args):
        # No more self...
        print 'My *args* is {}'.format(args)

Example().print_stuff(1, 2, 3)
# My *args* is (1, 2, 3)
```

A hypothetical implementation of `staticmethod` might look something like this:

```
def staticmethod_example(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) # Notice how *self* is thrown away
    return wrapper
```

`classmethod` removes the implicit `self` argument from a function, but adds the instance class as an argument instead.

```
class Example:
    @classmethod
    def print_stuff(cls, *args):
        print 'My *cls* is {}'.format(cls)
        print 'My *args* is {}'.format(args)

Example().print_stuff(1, 2, 3)
# My *cls* is __main__.Example
# My *args* is (1, 2, 3)
```

A hypothetical implementation of `classmethod` might look something like this:

```
def classmethod_example(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(self.__class__, *args, **kwargs) # Substitute *cls* for *self*
    return wrapper
```

To answer your question, your function call is printing the instance of the class because it is being passed `self` implicitly. If you add the `staticmethod` decorator above the function declaration, it will work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful and helpful answers. My mind has clearly shed more of Python than I thought. Guess it is apt I re-educate myself.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `multiArgsPrinter3(*args)` is catching `self` inside of `*args`. You just need to change the signature to `multiArgsPrinter3(self, *args)`, and it'll work.

```
class TestHelper:
    """"The TestHelper Class"""
    def multi_args_printer(self, *args):
        test_string = ''
        for thing in args:
            test_string += str(thing) + ","
        print(test_string)
        return test_string

print(TestHelper().multi_args_printer(20, 30, 40))  # Prints "20,30,40,"
```

As a side note, unless you want the trailing comma, you should use `join`. Eg, `','.join(map(str,args))`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make it a `staticmethod` since it's a static method? It might require more explanation about bound instance methods implicitly being passed the instance, but it's weird to have an instance method that makes no use of the instance.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Sure, if this were production code. As it is, I don't want to confuse the OP with decorators and whatnot.

Comment: the `join` alternative should be `','.join(map(str,args))` because `join` don't make a automatic conversion for thing that are not string

Comment: Thanks for the insightful and helpful answers. My mind has clearly shed more of Python than I thought. Guess it is apt I re-educate myself.